# One function for two events

Tags: c#

I have this code that I attach to the `DoubleClick` event on the Tray Icon for my app:

```
ni.DoubleClick +=
  delegate(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            this.MainWindow.Show();
        };
```

But, is it possible to use this code for two events (`DoubleClick` and `Click`), like so:

```
ni.DoubleClick, ni.Click +=
  delegate(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            this.MainWindow.Show();
        };
```

Just for minimalize a code size and readability. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just create `EventHandler` using lambda expression and add it to both event.

```
EventHandler e = (sender, args) => this.MainWindow.Show();
ni.DoubleClick += e;
ni.Click += e;
```

Answer (score 21):

Put the handler in its own function:

```
private void ClickHandler(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    this.MainWindow.Show();
}
```

Then wire it up to both events:

```
ni.DoubleClick += ClickHandler;
ni.Click += ClickHandler;
```

Answer (score 5):

No, but you can make it a standard, non anonymous function and use it for both events.

```
private void OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e) { ... }

ni.DoubleClick += OnClick;
ni.Click += OnClick;
```

Comment: Okay :( Thanks for fast answer

Answer (score 4):

Just assign it to a variable beforehand:

```
EventHandler eventHandler = delegate(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        this.MainWindow.Show();
    };

ni.DoubleClick += eventHandler;
ni.Click += eventHandler;
```

BTW, the event handler definition can be simplified using the anonymous method syntax:

```
EventHandler eventHandler = (s, e) => this.MainWindow.Show();
```

Comment: this will also work, but be aware you'll need to hold onto the eventHandler variable if you later want to unregister from the event.

Comment: @MattGreer The same is true with the code he was using in the OP.  I find only a small percent of such handlers need to be unsubscribed, and it's not terribly hard to deal with them when that's the case.

Comment: @MattGreer: According to the question this is not something he wants to do. His current solution with one event doesn't allow unregistering either.

Comment: You can actually unregister these anyway using `(event as MulticastDelegate).GetInvocationList()` to find the method and then unregister it as normal.